# Use python code to extract all attributes shapefile

Tags: arcpy, split-by-attribute

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.

How to use ArcPy code to extract every row in the attribute table and save each row to separate shapefiles?

Comment: What do you mean "extract every attribute"?

Comment: Please add a code sample of what you have tried so far

Comment: What kind of output/result do you want?

Comment: need to re-define your question

Comment: I mean I would like to extract every row in the attribute table of a shapefile. And save each of them to separate shapefiles.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Split tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/split.htm), as described here: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000008282

In newer versions of ArcGIS, you can use the [Split By Attributes tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/split-by-attributes.htm).

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if there is a way to clip line features with every polygon I extract and save as separate line shapefiles?

Comment: @Rachel, for that, you can just use the Split tool again. If you have specific needs for where everything is stored or how the outputs are named, then you might need to resort to ArcPy, but the general needs can be met simply with Split.

Comment: I don't have the split attributes in the line shapefile. I wonder how to use the polygons to quickly clip with less steps.

Comment: @Rachel, run Split using the lines as the input features and using the polygons as the split features.